# Two-dimensional array uses memcpy and a segmentation fault occurs

Tags: c

I'm learning how to work with 2D arrays and how to use `memcpy`, I wrote the `array_test` test function as follows:

```c
void array_test(void)
{
    int arr[3][5] = {{0, 1, 1, 0, 1}, {1, 1, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 0, 0, 1, 0}};
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for (size_t j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
            printf("%d ", arr[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    int row = 3;
    int col = 5;
    int **arr2 = (int **)malloc(sizeof(int *) * row);
    if (!arr2) {
        printf("arr2 malloc failed\n");
        exit(-1);
    }
    memset(arr2, 0, sizeof(int *) * row);
    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
        arr2[i] = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int) * col);
        if (!arr2[i]) {
            printf("arr2[%d] malloc failed\n", i);
            exit(-1);
        }
        memset(arr2[i], 0, sizeof(int) * col);
    }
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for (size_t j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
            printf("%d ", arr2[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    memcpy(arr2, arr, sizeof(int) * 3 * 5);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for (size_t j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
            printf("%d ", arr2[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

After the above is executed normally, I expected the copy to be successful, but the following segmentation error occurred. Why?

```
0 1 1 0 1
1 1 1 1 1
1 0 0 1 0
0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0
Segmentation fault
```

Comment: `memcpy(arr2, arr, sizeof(int) * 3 * 5);` - `arr` is a 2-dimensional array, contiguous in memory. `arr2` is essentially an array of pointers, which your are overwriting with integers here - that cannot work

Comment: Instead of `malloc(); memset();` do `calloc()`.

Comment: Or, replace the row-by-row `memset()` with a row-by-row `memcpy()`. As pointed out by @UnholySheep, `arr` and `arr2` are not the same species. (AND, do not cast the returned pointer from `malloc()`. It's unnecessary and adds more possibilities for bugs to enter your code.)

Comment: You should [edit[ and show a [mcve]

Comment: Litmus test: `printf( "arr %zu vs arr2 %zu\n", sizeof arr, sizeof arr2 );`... Explain why these values are different...

Comment: arr2 is an int ** type, and arr is essentially an int (*)[] type

Comment: No, `arr` is of type `int[][]` and decays in certain cases to `int (*)[]`.

Comment: There are 4 separate calls to `malloc`. There is no reason to believe that this will result in a single memory block (which `memcpy` expects).

Comment: You should allocate a 2D array as `int (*arr2)[5] = malloc(3 * 5 * sizeof(int));` so your allocation is contiguous, yet still an array of arrays. (The type of `arr2` is a pointer to objects of type `int[5]`).

Comment: Check out [Correctly allocating multi-dimensional arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42094465/correctly-allocating-multi-dimensional-arrays), which is probably a duplicate of this question.

Comment: Consider: `arr2[i] = malloc(sizeof(int) * col);` could be modified: `arr2[i] = malloc(sizeof(int) * (col * (i+1));` giving 3 rows of 5, 10 and 15 elements each... Do you see why `arr[][]` and `arr2[][]` are not the same species?

Answer (score 2):

as others have pointed out, `arr2` is one dimensional; it is a one dimensional array of pointers to integers. if you want to copy it, you'll have to do something like this:

```c
for (i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
    memcpy(arr2[i], arr[i], (sizeof(int) * col));
}
```

instead of the single memcpy you are trying to do

Answer (score 0):

> ... but the following segmentation error occurred. Why?

With `memcpy(arr2, arr, sizeof(int) * 3 * 5);` - `int arr[3][5]` is a 2-dimensional array, contiguous in memory. `int **arr2` is a pointer to a 1-dimensional array of pointers, which code is overwriting with integers here.
That cannot work. [@UnholySheep](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77271578/c-language-two-dimensional-array-uses-memcpy-and-a-segmentation-fault-occurs#comment136224987_77271578).

Answer (score 0):

The 2 objects `arr` and `arr2` have a different layout:

- `arr` is a 2D array of `int`, ie: an array of 3 arrays of 5 `int`. It occupies a single span of memory of length `3 * 5 * sizeof(int)` bytes.
- `arr2` conversely is an array of 3 pointers to `int`, each initialized to point to arrays of 5 `int` allocated separately.

You cannot copy the values in `arr` to the corresponding elements of `arr2` in a single call to `memcpy`.  You need to copy the arrays of 5 `int` individually with:

```
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        memcpy(arr2[i], arr[i], sizeof(int) * 5);
    }
```

Note that instead of `sizeof(int) * 5`, you can write `sizeof(arr[i])`  which is less error prone as it will not get out of sync with the actual number of columns, should you change them.  Here is an alternative without hardcoded row and column numbers, assuming `arr` is defined as a 2D array:

```
    for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]); i++) {
        memcpy(arr2[i], arr[i], sizeof(arr[i]));
    }
```

The reason for the segmentation fault is undefined behavior: your `memcpy` call writes beyond the end of the array pointed to by `arr2`, corrupting whatever follows in memory, if accessible at all. Furthermore, the data written to `arr2[0]` and beyond form invalid pointers, which cause a segmentation fault when dereferenced in the final output code.